# Can -que be attached to a word ending in -que?

Tags: example-request, conjunction, enclitic

Some Latin words end in *-que* (for example *quinque*, vocative of adjectives ending in *-quus* and imperatives like *relinque*), but I have never seen the conjunction *-que* attached to such words.
Are there examples of having a double *-que* in this sense?
Do grammarians or other writers suggest avoiding such combinations?

I am not interested in pronouns where the final *-que* comes from the conjunction, but in words that coincidentally end in *-que*.
The answers to [an earlier question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/567/79) indicate that *quinque* does not have the conjunction *-que* in it.

**Added detail:**
I am mostly interested in the case where both 'e's are short, that is, words ending in *-quĕquĕ* instead of *-quēquĕ*.
The answer by brianpck below gives an example with *-quēquĕ*.

Comment: A fascinating thought and question! I can't wait to see the answer....

Answer (score 11):

I searched through plausible forms (particularly adverbial forms of adjectives ending in -quus) and only found one example:

## Aequeque

> in rebus minoribus socium fallere turpissimum est **aequeque** turpe atque illud de quo ante dixi ([Cic. S. Rosc. 40](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0010%3Atext%3DS.+Rosc.%3Achapter%3D40))
>
> simili quae praedita constant
> natura atque ipsae res sunt **aequeque** laborant
> et pereunt ([Lucr. 1.847](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0130%3Abook%3D1%3Acard%3D847))

Otherwise, I have not found one example, even in later Latin writings. All search results for these are either typos (*usqueque* for *usquequo*) or bad machine transcriptions (*propinqueque* for *propinquaeque*).

It does not take much imagination to see that most words in the [relatively short list of Latin words ending in *-que*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?lang=la&type=end&page=1&lookup=que) would complain if a -que was added.

1. It does not take a sensitive soul to cringe at the **dissonance** of such words as *usqueque*, *quicumqueque*, or (my favorite) *jamjamqueque*.
2. Many words ending in -que **already use the ending -que**, e.g. *itaque*, *neque*, and *atque*

Comment: I wanted to add--but just didn't have the sources to back up--that the host of relative pronouns ending in -que,, e.g. *quicumque* and *quisque*, are related to the ending -que. Anyone know if this is the case?

Comment: OMG *jamjamqueque* makes me incredibly happy. It's like when I had to go to the hospital and they told me I had a jejunojejunal intussusception.

Comment: Thanks! It should be noted, though, that the word you propose ends in *-quēque*, not a *-queque* with two short 'e's. My original intention was in the doubly short version (where dissonance seems worse), which I should have spelled out. The list does not include inflected forms, so verbs ending in *-quere* and adjectives ending in *-quus* are absent. Anyhow, your finding is interesting (and of course worth my +1).

Comment: Good answer. If you simply search for `queque` (no word boundaries enforced) in the HP corpus, you find only 2 results, both *aequeque*. http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=queque

Comment: Cool--and I didn't even know about that tool! I ended up going with intuition because I couldn't find a way to search Google without word boundaries, e.g. *queque

Comment: Going back a bit further, pre-Latin _quīquomqueque_ would be fantastic, but utterly unpronounceable.